# How to find a purpose at life

Tags: self, self-cognition

Just watched the How to Know Your Life Purpose in 5 Minutes: Adam Leipzig at TEDxMalibu

He talks about 3 questions.

- Who you are ?(%90)
- What do you love to do "X" ? (%80)
- Who do you do "X" for ? ( who is the market ) (%70)
- What do they want of need ?   (%40)
- How do they change when you fill create the result ? (%15)

And the percents are my self efficacy when rated myself on the answers. What are the pros and cons of this approach and how could we make this question better?

Reference
http://tedxtalks.ted.com/video/How-to-Know-Your-Life-Purpose-i

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain a little bit more here about the *specific* question you're trying to answer? What exactly would you like someone here to explain to you? What have you discovered so far through your own research?

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the video: I think it goes to much in to practical detail at first. I would like to come at this from a more abstract level.

> What is the purpose of being able to always serve a higher purpose?

You are conscious. Consciousness is ALL there is. Consciousness creates purpose. Become more consciousness and you find (create) more purpose in life. There is no end to that. Just likea fractal has no end and can become more and more complex when energy is put in to the formula to create a fractal. Consciousness wants (needs) to evolve. So the purpose of us all is to learn how to create synergy. As that is how we grow. So in the most abstract concept, your life's purpose is exactly the same as mine.
The videos five questions can be derived from the purpose, that ALL there is (which is conscious) wants (needs) to evolve.

Now you can go into more detail. How can I serve ALL there is? By creating synergy. Doing what you are good at. Because you can create more synergy with what your good at than by struggling with things you s*ck at in a certain period of time.

Now derive his 5 questions from the concept above, and I think that is your answer.

To touch a little more upon what the video says:
He talks about finding out what other people need and how to make them happy. Altruism is key to serving a larger system. The opposite, ego, is destructive for a larger system. If you create synergy with someone else, you become more, and that person becomes more. So in that case you are also altruistic, because you serve what they need.

Only looking at your title:
I could have typed: Find *a* purpose by asking whether you could be of help to someone (in the scheme of creating synergy, not by serving their ego's). Than there is *a* purpose. :D Just kidding though!

Comment: Alturism and synergy is critical. Suffering from my narcissist nature which i got from my dad unconsciously

Answer (score 2):

This approach is thinking free: it's certainly really good for human beings whose brain is enslaved by their impulses and pathological need for happiness and pleasure, but not for philosophers.

Maybe it's time to ask yourself what's the difference between a **meaningful** purpose and a monkey-like purpose. A better question could be "why should I live?". Try to answer it meaningfully if you care about freedom. Another question could be "what is the difference between a human being and a monkey?".